# Plotting an float array in julia

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I have the following code

```
using Plots

function test()::nothing
  A::Array{Float64,1} = rand(Float64,100)
  plot(A)
end
```

Which I run in julia like this

```
julia> include("main.jl")
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test()
ERROR: MethodError: First argument to `convert` must be a Type, got nothing
Stacktrace:
 [1] test() at /path/to/main.jl:85
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1
```

Why do I get the error `First argument to convert must be a Type, got nothing` ?

Comment: Well, you have to write `Nothing`. Or better yet, nothing at all, since it is not necessary to annotate types unless needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this problem is related to the fact that you were using `nothing` in annotation, but correct type is `Nothing` (note capital `N`). `nothing` is an object, `Nothing` is a type of this object.

So you should use something like

```
function test()::Nothing
  A::Array{Float64,1} = rand(Float64, 100)
  display(plot(A))
  nothing
end
```

Note, that I had to add `nothing` as return value and explicit `display` to show actual plot.

But, to be honest, main problem is not the `Nothing`, but overspecialization. Type annotations in functions do not speed up calculations, you should use them only when they are really needed, for example in multiple dispatch.

Idiomatic code looks like this

```
function test()
  A = rand(100)
  plot(A)
end
```

Note, that I removed all extra annotations and unnecessary `Float64` in `rand`, since it is default value.